# How can i solve my bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in bootstrap and css, and I want to design this output:
[image: this output]

For that purpose write this :

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-1 col-md-4 col-md-8" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-left">
                <div class="container">
                    behzad
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-md-1">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But that is not correct, how can I solve that?

Comment: I don't understand from the pictures. You want 12 columns across or more? The navbar should not be within the row. It should be outside the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using bootstrap correctly. Put your `col` definitions within separate `div`'s: Also make use of bootstrap's `xs`, and `md` definitions. Finally, put your `row` inside a container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/zf0q5cLk/3/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap should follow pattern: `container` - `row` - `col`. Then use `-xs` (xsmall devices), `-sm` (small devices), `-md` (medium devices), `-lg` (large devices) to change grid design based on device.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
           <!-- Left panel, top panel on mobile device -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
           <!-- Content -->
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <!-- First empty col (Also can use offset) -->
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">

               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">

               </div>
                   .
                   .
                   .
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <!-- Last empty col (Also can use offset) -->
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If u want to use `col-offset` try this approach:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
           <!-- Left panel, top panel on mobile device -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-1">

                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-1">

                 </div>
                     .
                     .
                     .
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Offset moves columns to the right using `.col-xs(sm, md, lg)-offset-*`. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. In this example, `.col-xs-offset-2` moves columns over two columns.